# When is a proth number a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

I am investigating when a Proth number is a perfect square. I saw a very short proof in [this article (Lemma 3.1)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11139-021-00536-2.pdf), but I want it more number-theoretic.

A Proth number $n$ is a number of the form
$$
n = h\cdot 2^k + 1 \text{ with } k\in\mathbb N \text { and } h<2^k \text { odd.}
$$
So lets suppose we have $h\cdot 2^k + 1 = q^2$ for a $q\in\mathbb N$. Then
$$
h\cdot 2^k = q^2 - 1 = (q+1)\cdot (q-1).
$$
Since $h\cdot 2^k$ is even, so is $(q+1)(q-1)$. That means that both $q+1$ and $q-1$ are even.
Since their difference is $2$, it follows that one of these is divisible by $2$ exactly once.
And the other is divisible by $2$ exactly $2^{m-1}$ times.

But how do I go on from here?

Comment: A proof of what ? Make the question self-contained (+1 nevertheless)